# Python/Pandas: Transformation of column within a list of columns

Tags: pandas

I'd like to select a subset of columns from a DataFrame while applying a transformation to some of those columns at the same time. Is it possible to transform a column when that column is selected as one in a list of columns?

For example, I have a column `StartDate` that is of type `np.datetime[64]` that I'd like to extract the month from.

When dealing with that Series on its own, I'd do something like

```
print(df['StartDate'].transform(lambda x: x.month))
```

to see the transformed data. Can I accomplish the same thing when the above expression is part of a list of columns? Something like:

```
print(df[['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'StartDate'.transform(lambda x: x.month)]])
```

Of course the above gives the error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'
```

So, if my data looks like:

```
Metadata | Metadata | 2020-01-01
Metadata | Metadata | 2020-02-06
Metadata | Metadata | 2020-02-25
```

I'd like to see:

```
Metadata | Metadata | 1
Metadata | Metadata | 2
Metadata | Metadata | 2
```

Without appending a new separate "Month" column to the DataFrame. Is this possible?

Comment: What are the dtypes of `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`

Comment: They are different (object/string), so I can't .apply the whole df.

Comment: Are you trying to just convert `StartDate` to months and then add this back into your dataframe? Can you add some sample data and the expected output please>

Comment: Not add to the data -- just view it a different way. See updated question above.

Comment: I understand, see below

Answer (score 3):

If you have some data like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : np.random.randint(10, size = 366), 'col2': np.random.randint(10, size = 366),'StartDate' : pd.date_range('2018', '2019')})
```

which looks like

```
    col1    col2    StartDate
0      0       2    2018-01-01
1      8       0    2018-01-02
2      0       5    2018-01-03
3      3       4    2018-01-04
4      8       6    2018-01-05
...  ...     ...    ...
361    8       8    2018-12-28
362    9       9    2018-12-29
363    4       1    2018-12-30
364    2       4    2018-12-31
365    0       9    2019-01-01
```

You could redefine the column, or you could assign and create a temporary view, like.

```
df.assign(StartDate = df['StartDate'].dt.month)
```

which outputs.

```
    col1    col2    StartDate
0      0       2            1
1      8       0            1
2      0       5            1
3      3       4            1
4      8       6            1
...  ...     ...          ...
361    8       8           12
362    9       9           12
363    4       1           12
364    2       4           12
365    0       9            1
```

This also doesn't change the original dataframe. If you want to create a permanent version, then just reassign.

```
df = df.assign(StartDate = df['StartDate'].dt.month)
```

You could also take this further, such as.

```
df.assign(StartDate = df['StartDate'].dt.month, col1 = df['col1'] + 100)[['col1', 'StartDate']]
```

You can apply whatever transform you need and then access any columns you want after assigning these transforms.

```
    col1    StartDate
0    105            1
1    109            1
2    108            1
3    101            1
4    108            1
...  ...          ...
361  104           12
362  102           12
363  109           12
364  102           12
365  100            1
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use the attribute `name` of the Series.
Something like:

```py
dt_to_month = lambda x: [d.month for d in x] if x.name == 'StartDate' else x
df[['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'StartDate']].apply(dt_to_month)
```

will do the trick.